# Animating Progress Bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to create a Quiz app that consists of two buttons, false and true button. My question is, as I answer more questions in the app, I want the progress bar to complete until I get to the last question where the entire Progress Bar is full. And then when I circle back to the first question again, it resets. This is my code so far. I'm looking forward to your answers.

```js
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateUI()
        progressBar.progress = 0.0
    }

    @IBAction func answerButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle
        let actualAnswer = quiz[questionNumber].answer

        if userAnswer == actualAnswer {
            sender.shortChangeTo(.green)
        } else {
            sender.shortChangeTo(.red)
         }
        
        if questionNumber + 1 < quiz.count {
        
        questionNumber += 1
            }
        else {
            questionNumber = 0
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            self.updateUI()
        }
        
        }
        
    func updateUI() {
        questionLabel.text = quiz[questionNumber].text
        trueButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        falseButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this inside `updateUI`

```
progressBar.progress = Float(questionNumber) / Float(quiz.count - 1)
```

Comment: Xcode says, *No exact matches in reference to instance method 'value'*.

Comment: It worked when I replaced 'res' with Float(res).

Comment: But I encountered a small problem in the simulator, the progress bar is not full when I get to the last question.